# How long does Springer give you to proof your entire book?

Tags: publications, proofreading

I know it's 48 or 72 hours for an article, how long does the author have to check the proofs for an entire book (300 pages)?

Comment: The answer is specific to your contract with Springer.

Comment: Your question is about a book., not articles.

Answer (score 4):

Ask your editor to be sure, but from my experience with other publishers you can expect 2-4 weeks before the editor starts chasing you about the proofs.

Comment: A month seems like a lot of time, when they give you 48 hours to proofread 10,000 words!

Comment: (+1) For my 343 page monograph, I had less than a month to check the final proofs and had to do the index, which is a *nightmare*, to say the least. And the final proofs, in pdf format, were locked and the publication folks, half a world away, simply gave up trying to help me unlock them. It turns out that was just the usual Windows and Mac problem, i.e., cross-platform compatibility is still mostly just a fever dream, so I hacked the final proofs to get to correct errors. With apologies to Chief Joseph, “From where the sun now sits in the sky, I will book publish no more, forever!”

Comment: Don’t know when this was, but Springer now uses an online proof checker that’s awesome… at least for articles. I hope they use the same for books.

Comment: @user354948 journal papers are usually more time-sensitive than books though (and are you rerea.ding the entire thing?).

Comment: @Allure Yes, I am. I’ve had experiences in the past of editors not fluent in English changing a sentence of mine into grammatically nonsensical English. I had to publish and erratum in that occasion.